# is possible to interupt a post deletion when empty the trash

Tags: trash

it is possible once called a *before_delete_post* action not to allow WP to delete post on certain condition?
something like e this:

```
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'my_custom_delete', 10);

function my_custom_delete($wp_post_id) {
    if (get_post_type($wp_post_id) == 'my_custom_post_type') {
         if(condition_is_true($wp_post_id)){
              error_log("do something to block WP deleting the post");
              notify_the_user();
         }
         else {
              error_log("we can delete the post");
         }

     }
}
```

Comment: is your goal to prevent posts being deleted? If so there are other options, e.g. preventing the empty trash posts routine from seeing those posts, hiding them from trash, or preventing them ever reaching trash in the first place. What you've asked isn't the only way to solve these problems. Can you add some context for why you want to do this to the question? It will help people write better answers

Comment: The goal is to prevent some posts from being deleted if a certain condition is met, the condition is checked outside WP database with a request with a completely separate API. The human operator must be able to trash the post and flush the trash as usual without changing the usual WP workflow habit. (to be more clear wp_untrash_post is not an option)

Comment: Redirect the user away if the condition is met. Or `exit( 'with some explanation message' );`

Comment: @MaxYudin that means no posts can be deleted if one of these posts is in the trash

Comment: @Totoro3D this means deleting will be significantly slower, especially if you make this request when the trash is being emptied/post is being deleted. As I mentioned earlier though, I do not believe this filter is usable for your purpose, or that this approach is ideal. If there is more context about why you need to do this or what the condition is then there may even be solutions that never send it to the trash in the first place but still achieve your goals. E.g. if you're just trying to hide the posts, or if they're representing something else